# Search on multiple lists under multiple levels with linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

This will be quick and dirty, but should give you the idea. I've done it before, but can't find where I did it, nor can I remember since it's been so long. I need to search on multiple levels of lists....

Example: Seach for "pig"

```
var query = context.Farms.OrderBy(x => x.FarmName).Select(f => new FarmItem
{
    FarmId = f.FarmId,
    FarmName = f.FarmName,                    
    Fields = f.Fields.OrderBy(x => x.FieldName).Select(d => new FieldItem
    {
        FieldId = d.FieldId,
        FieldName = d.FieldName,
        Animals = d.Animals.OrderBy(x => x.AnimalName).Select(a => new AnimalItem
        {
            AnimalId = a.AnimalId,
            AnimalName = a.AnimalName
        })
    })
});
```

I need to see if "pig" is in FarmName, FieldName, or AnimalName and

1. return the farm if "pig" is found in the name, and all of it's fields, and it's field's animals
2. return the fields with "pig" in it's name as well as it's farm, and all the field's animals
3. return the plans with "pig" in it's name as well as it's field, and it's field's farm

Answer (score 0):

This should work (untested):

```
var query = context.Farms.OrderBy(x => x.FarmName).Select(f => new FarmItem
{
    FarmId = f.FarmId,
    FarmName = f.FarmName,                    
    Fields = f.Fields.OrderBy(x => x.FieldName).Select(d => new FieldItem
    {
        FieldId = d.FieldId,
        FieldName = d.FieldName,
        Animals = d.Animals.OrderBy(x => x.AnimalName).Select(a => new AnimalItem
        {
            AnimalId = a.AnimalId,
            AnimalName = a.AnimalName
        }).Where(a => a.AnimalName.Contains("pig"))
    }).Where(d => d.FieldName.Contains("pig") || d.Animals.Any())
}).Where(d => f.FarmName.Contains("pig") || f.Fields.Any());
```

Comment: Wouldn't that cut out all the animals if no FieldName.Contains("pig"), and fields if farm didn't contain "pig".. so on.

Comment: Really I would need to see if it's in farms, then see if it's in fields, then see if it's in animals. If not in any hide the farm.

Comment: No. That's why the Where clause is after the Select. You may need a .ToEnumerable() call between them.  A field is included if it's name contains "pig" or if the sequence assigned to its Animals property has any elements.  This would only be the case if one or more of the animals in that field has "pig" in its name.  The same logic works for the Farms.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.SortOp' to type 'System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp'.

Looking for a solution, or a work around...

Comment: There's a problem with this. If "pig" is found at the farm level it doesn't return all the fields and all the animals.

Comment: So you want to return everything in the tree under any instance of "pig".  Is that correct?

Comment: If a parent has "pig" all of it's children should be returned.

Comment: ***SELECT f.FarmId, f.FarmName, d.FieldId, d.FieldName, a.AnimalId, a.AnimalName 
     FROM Farms AS f
      INNER JOIN Fields AS d ON d.FarmId = f.FarmId
      INNER JOIN Animals AS a on p.FieldId = d.FieldId
     WHERE (f.FarmName LIKE '%pig%' OR d.FieldName LIKE '%pig%' OR p.PlanName LIKE '%pig%') 
     ORDER BY f.FarmId, f.FarmName, d.FieldId, d.FieldName, a.AnimalId, a.AnimalName ***

but I want to make use of the objects...